# Universal cover of quotient space of a disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I need to find the universal covering space of $X=D^2 / \sim$ where $x \sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $ x,y \in S^1$ and $q(x)=q(y)$. Here $q: S^1 \mapsto S^1$ is n sheeted covering space of the circle.

This is what I am thinking: for n=2, this is the disk with antipodal points identified and we know that in this case the universal covering of the real projective plane is $S^2$. I know how to prove this when we consider the real projective plane as the sphere with antipodal points identified (rather than disk with antipodal points identified). Also, in this case $q$ is 2-sheeted covering space and our universal covering $p$ is 2 sheeted (which makes sense because $\pi_1(RP_2)=Z_2$).

Now, for our $X$, it is not hard to prove that $\pi_1(X)=Z_n$. So, I think our universal covering space is going to be n sheeted covering space. But I am having trouble to see what it could be. Is it also a sphere $S^2$ with some particular properties? And if so, how to prove it?

Comment: The universal cover cannot be sphere because there is no neighbourhood of S^2 which is homeomorphic to a neighbourhood of the identified points of the boundary circle.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the real projective plane? $S^2$ is the universal covering for the real projective plane

Comment: The real projective plane is a manifold. So, the problem I mentioned above doesn't arise in that case.

Comment: To slightly expand on Ajay Kumar Nair's comment, when you take a cross section of the identified boundary circle, you'll see an $n$-pointed star, since you are gluing the disk to the circle $n$ times. When $n=1$ or $n=2$, you have a 1 or 2 pointed star, which can be part of a manifold with boundary, or a manifold respectively, but as soon as $n\ge 3$, we have something that doesn't look like a manifold anymore.

Comment: Oh okay. So what's the universal covering space in this case?

Comment: It should be $n$-copies of $D^2$ with their boundary circles identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written for 3-sheeted covering of circle. But this is generalizable.

Take three discs and identify them along their boundary and consider the following quotient map where same coloured regions are identified. This will give you the universal covering.[image]

It is easy to see that this space is simply connected and the cover is 3-fold.

Comment: Okay and this makes sense! Because for n=2, we get 2 disks with their boundary circles identified which is $S^2$. Right?

Comment: Also, this space is homeomorphic to a subset of $R^3$?

Comment: The same construction works for $n=2$ also. Yes, it can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @AjayKumarNair Sorry, do you mind explaining what the rotation of the discs does? I can't see why that would be necessary, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: Identification via this rotation gives us the covering map. In the case of real projective plane, the antipodal map is exactly this kind of identification with two regions.